# Responsive centered menu while the menu buttons need tot resize too

Tags: css, responsive-design, menu, center

I am trying to make a page responsive. It worked out fine with two simple div's for a logo. The logo resizes too. For the menu I want to create the same, only this is a list and I find it hard to center the buttons. I came this far, but it isn't center aligned like I wanted. Only when it's minimum screen size.

```css
@charset"UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Algemeen*/

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
header {
  padding-bottom: 8%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #88d9ce;
}
#logo {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#logo img {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}
#menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 17%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
li img {
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/13yebnr.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/5f0pd4.png" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/2cx6xqs.png" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/veu6o1.png" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/24ebywg.png" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/71r8ut.png" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at this link for help http://learnlayout.com
You have not provided a working jsfiddle nor images that we can see. The community is here to help but you need to provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: I'll make a jsfiddle to show how it looks. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Put your other code back in there so it doesn't get voted down. A fiddle and the code in the question is the preferred way of asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` for your `li` then it centers with `text-align:center`. The `font-size:0px` on the `ul` is to remove the extra spacing that happens. If you have text in that list item, put the font size on that.

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/xudaz/1/

```
   <div id="logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100/000000/FFFFFF&text=LOGO" />
    </div>
   
    <ul id="menu">
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=1"/></li>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=2"/></li>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=3"/></li>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=4"/></li>
       <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=5"/></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#logo img {
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:15%;
    height:auto;
}

#menu {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    font-size:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    min-width:240px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    max-width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:17%;
}
#menu li img {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I tried to apply your code to mine and I've found that it's not centered, I think the menu buttons that have to resize responsive to the width is causing the problem.. http://jsbin.com/fazirolubo

Comment: It centers in the Bin, look carefully that I have remove the #menu div and put the styles on the ul also you had negative margin and various other styles I removed.

Comment: YES! I edited the menu div to al ul id and it worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Cool. The float also on the li has to be removed (since float only goes left or right). Please accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate "answer" as it's not using images at all. You will find that images used for navigation, unless they are twice the size, will look fuzzy on high density (retina) devices. Also, sizing down links too small on small viewports is hard to tap on as a finger is kinda fat. This stacks better.

## DEMO: https://jsbin.com/fafeya/1/

[image]

**CSS**

```
body,
html {
    background: #88d9ce;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 3% auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:5px solid #000;
}
#nav {
    text-align: center
}
#nav a {
    background: #9cf2e6;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:monospace; /* see google fonts too or typekit etc */
    padding: 5px 20px 3px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(2deg) skew(2deg);
    margin: 5px 3%;
}
#nav a span {
    transform: rotate(-2deg) skew(-2deg);
    display: block;
}
#nav a:nth-child(even) {
    transform: rotate(-2deg) skew(-2deg)
}
#nav a:nth-child(even) span {
    transform: rotate(2deg) skew(2deg)
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="logo"></div>
  
  
<nav id="nav">
  <a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
</nav>
```